# React-Natice-Reanimated not found

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I have the following Error

```
error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyApp/MyMobileApp/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/Common/cpp/Registries/WorkletsCache.cpp' (in target 'RNReanimated' from project 'Pods')
```

i have done already a "pod install" in the ios folder.

Does anybody know why?

My node_modules contains the "react-native-reanimated" folder

Comment: Try run pod repo update.

Comment: I dont make anything. The error is still there. I cleand up my project first

Comment: Try yarn clean and accept every option it asks.  This is clear node modules and everything else.  Then try run pod install.

Comment: Thank you, works. But now i a following error:
TypeError: ReanimatedModule.installTurboModule is not a function. (In 'ReanimatedModule.installTurboModule()', 'ReanimatedModule.installTurboModule' is undefined)

Comment: If you are still having this issue, it may be a versioning issue: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3130